# SSIS - How can I set the escape character?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am a novice when it comes to SSIS packages. I'm editing an existing package and adding a new column. The column delimiter is a vertical bar `{|}` and there are vertical bars that are being escaped with a `\`, but SSIS doesn't seem to be picking this up.

Do I need to set the escape character? I'm editing the package in Visual Studio in the Design mode. If the answer is to put something in the XML, please me detailed enough that I can figure it out.

A sample line from the flat file is below.

> 1234|4567|12345|4.01|0.00|0.00|3.99|0.00|\|CAS:45\|CAS:3|0.00|3.99

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There should be no any issue because of . It should be perfectly fine. If you have more details of the issues please post it.
I have tested in the below package

https://www.dropbox.com/s/qoyx9oebzziuzad/deli.zip

Comment: When I try to import my full file using the package you've attached, I get the same behavior. In other words, when it tries to import a line like the one that I've provided above, the first '\' ends up in the 9th column. CAS:45\ ends up in the 10th column, etc. I should say that we are still using VS 2008 to edit these.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: can you attach the flatfile with some sample?